# QGIS quits unexpectedly after install "Import Photo" plugin on MX Linux

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I install "import photo" plugin in QGIS 2.14 in MX Linux 18 via menu Plugins >  Manage and Install Plugin. No message on success or not, then QGIS quits unexpectedly. Then I try to open QGIS again. But, QGIS quits again. So, I uninstall QGIS and install QGIS again. But, QGIS still quits unexpectedly.

Then I update and upgrade to MX Linux 19. QGIS still quits unexpectedly. So, I uninstall and install QGIS. QGIS still quits unexpectadly. So, I delete file `user.py` and `user.pyc` in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/`. There is a message:

> Couldn't load qgis.user. 
> Python support will be disabled.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) ImportError: No module named user

Then I close. After that QGIS runs well. But, I can not install plugin anymore because in Setting tab (Plugins > Manage and Install Plugin > Setting) there is message:

> "The settings on this tab are only for Python Plugins. No Python
>   support detected, thus no setting available."

So, any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, dont know much about this kind of errors and linux, but did you also try on QGIS 2.18, which is the latest and last V2.x (but also deprecated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should uninstall QGIS 2.14 move to QGIS 2.18 if you *must* stay with QGIS 2x for some reason. QGIS 2x is no longer supported.  If you can, move to QGIS 3x.

If you do want to stay with QGIS 2.14 - you'll need to reinstall it. You've corrupted your QGIS install by deleting `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/user.py*`.

Then you need to remove the plugin that is causing problems. Look for it in the [`~/.qgis2/python/plugins`](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html) folder and delete it.

Comment: I clean install MX Linux 19 and I update. After that, I install QGIS 2.18. The result is same (QGIS quit). Then I clean install again and I install QGIS 2.18. I have not updated. QGIS run.

Comment: I find the solution which I post in https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=54895&p=548073#p548073